# SoapUI update keystores/certificates for all projects

Tags: soap, soapui, soap-client

So we had a problem with ur soap projects Certificates and we have to update our file and pass for them

We have nearly 300 projects, is there any way to update them all at once?

Maybe a script for replacing in some xml files or smth?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The project files are plain XML files. When you know what you need to change, you can do it with replaceAll() in Groovy like this:

```
def projectFileA = new File('/path/to/your/soapui-project.xml')
def projectFileB = projectFileA.text.replaceAll('your old string', 'your new string')
projectfileA.text = projectfileB
```